# iPhone encoding removes part of string

Tags: iphone

In my application while parsing the XML I have a string in the foundcharacters delegate of XML parser. The actual string is 'Aoyama-itchōme Station' but when I apply the encoding I get it as 'ōme Station'. The first part of the string is lost. I tried different encodings but nothing worked for me. Does anyone have an idea about what is the cause?

Here is my code:

```cpp
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string
{
    if(titleFlag)
    {
       if(string)
       {
           objPlace.title   =   [string stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];
       }
    }
 }
```

Comment: You need to go for NSUnicodeStringEncoding, instead of NSUTF8StringEncoding.

Comment: i already tried NSUnicodeStringEncoding and NSASCIIStringEncoding. But it not worked for me...

Comment: Seems like it is japanese text, not sure though, you can go for NSUTF16StringEncoding. Might be this will fix your issue.

Comment: NSUTF16StringEncoding is not working. The strange thing is that when i don't use any any encoding still i'm getting the same response. Whats wrong with that. Iam struck!!!!

Comment: might be you can try the trick, not sure though if it will work, NSString *myString = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:[string cStringUsingEncoding:[NSString defaultCStringEncoding]]];

Comment: Else you need to with save whole string without parsing and then you need to manipulate that. One more option is from where you are getting this string if that is in your control(i.e. from server then you can ask them to correct the string before sending.)

Comment: `[string cStringUsingEncoding:[NSString defaultCStringEncoding]]` returns NULL and getting crashed

Comment: even if i extract that raw string from the xml response it contains percentage escapes right? inorder to make it correct we have to apply any of the encoding for that. Then it is reaching on the same road we are being now.

Comment: what is your complete string at this place, let me try instead something on that?Provide me the string that you want to parse.

Comment: `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<wikilocation><articles><article><id>5546351</id><lat>35.6729</lat><lng>139.724</lng><type>railwaystation</type><title>Aoyama-itch\u014dme Station</title><url>http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?curid=5546351</url><mobileurl>http://en.m.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?curid=5546351</mobileurl><distance>0m</distance></article></articles></wikilocation>`

Comment: The string in the title tag is our string.

Comment: I have tried this and it works for me fine, there is some other issue NSString *string = [@"Aoyama-itch\u014dme Station" stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"My String is -- %@",string);
    
    UILabel *myLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 300, 100)];
    myLabel.text = string;
    [self.view addSubview:myLabel];

Comment: this works perfectly fine, can you try logging what you are getting?

Comment: i found the problem, The NSXMLParser `foundcharacters` returns me the string as two. i mean when i got the frist call in 'foundCharacters' delegate the string is "Aoyama-itch" then in the next call i got "ōme Station". What i have to do? Please share your suggestion.

Comment: Thnkx for your very valuable help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'Aoyama-itch **ōme Station**' is the string what you are getting is '**ōme Station**'.

I guess when parsing the string is getting the first part 'Aoyama-itch' in the initial parsing and the second part 'ōme Station'. What you are doing is setting it to title.

So on initial parsing when parser finds charachters...

```
self.title = @"Aoyama-itch";
```

and in second set of availability...

```
self.title = @"ōme Station";
```

that is what you are seeing. So make the title object an NSMutableString object.

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string
{
   if(self.title==nil)
   {
      self .title = [[[NSMutableString alloc] init] autorelease];
   }
   [self.title appendString:<parsed Charachters>];
}
```